# Using :checked inside :not doesn't match with .on()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get a click event to bind to all radio inputs that are not checked in a specified section of the body. I'd also like this to bind to any new unchecked radio inputs in the future.

Based on the documentation ([.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), and [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)), I expected the following code to work:

```js
$(function() {
    var count = 0;
    $("#stuff").on("click", "div.gr input:not(:checked)", function(){
        $('div.gr').append("<label class='gr'><input type='radio' name='group3'>Another input "+(++count)+"</label>");
    });
});
```

However it does not ([jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vdQGb/1/)). If you replace `:not(:checked)` with `:not(.tmp)` it works ([jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eaKZx/1/)). Additionally, if you use [`.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) it works for existing inputs, but won't bind to new inputs ([jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nq9uA/)).

Why does `:not(:checked)` fail in `.on`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `on` on `#stuff` it will take help of event bubling and by the time the event reaches `#stuff` the radio button is already `checked` so the selector will not match.
Instead on `click` event use `mousedown` and change the selector to `div.gr label` it will work fine.

```
$(function() {
    var count = 0;
    $("#stuff").on(
        "mousedown",
        "div.gr label",
        function(){
            console.log($(this).find('input'));
            if(!$(this).find('input').is(':checked')){
                 $('div.gr').append("<label class='gr'><input type='radio' name='group3'>Another input "+(++count)+"</label>");
            }
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vdQGb/5/)**

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. But this breaks the label being clickable.

Comment: This still has corner cases which don't work (i.e. the user clicks and drags off). What I was ended up going with is to use a 'change' event.